# Can someone tell me what this song from episode 38 of Zero no Tsukaima is?

Tags: music, the-familiar-of-zero

I've looked through the soundtrack but I haven't been able to find this song. It plays in episode 38 "Louise of the Holy Ground" at 13:54.

Comment: do you mean season 4 episode 1 when louise and saito were arguing or a different scene?

Comment: yes it has appeared in other episodes but this is the episode I tried to look for it

Comment: if you do find it in the other episode, do you mind leaving it in the comments please?

Answer (score 1):

It's "Distress of Decision", track 22 of the [Zero no Tsukaima ~Futatsuki no Kishi~ Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/45062).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrFa_XdqGv4